# Error entre operaciones datetime.date y NoneType en Python

Tags: python

Teniendo en cuenta que `partidos` es una lista con sublistas que contienen tuplas. Ej: `partidos = [[(datetime.date(2000, 9, 9), 'FC Barcelona', 2, 'Málaga CF', 1)], [(datetime.date(2000, 9, 9), 'RC Deportivo', 2, 'Athletic Club', 0)], [(datetime.date(2000, 9, 9), 'Real Sociedad', 2, 'R. Racing C.', 2)]]`

He intentado construir la siguiente función para que realice lo que me pide:

```
def partidos_por_fecha(partidos, inicio=None, fin=None):
    ''' Filtra los partidos jugados en un rango de fechas

    ENTRADA: 
    - partidos: lista de partidos -> [Partido(datetime.date, str, int, str, int)]
    - inicio: fecha inicial del rango -> datetime.date
    - fin: fecha final del rango -> datetime.date
    SALIDA: 
    - lista de partidos seleccionados -> [Partido(datetime.date, str, int, str, int)] 

    Se devuelven aquellos partidos que se han jugado entre las fechas inicio
    y fin. Ambos parámetros serán objetos date del módulo datetime.
    Si inicio es None, se incluirán los partidos desde el principio de
    la serie, y si fin es None se inlcuirán los partidos hasta el último de
    la serie.
    '''
    if inicio == None:
        inicio = partidos[0][0][0]
    elif fin == None:
        fin = partidos[-1][-1][0]
    elif inicio == None and fin == None:
        inicio = partidos[0][0][0]
        fin = partidos[-1][-1][0]
    else:
        inicio == inicio
        fin == fin

    result = []
    for i in partidos:
        for fecha, local, goles_local, visitante, goles_visitante in i:
            if fecha >= inicio and fecha <= fin:
                result.append((fecha, local, goles_local, visitante, goles_visitante))
    return result
```

Esta función se ejecuta mediante el siguiente código:

```
def test_partidos_por_fechas(partidos):
    inicio = datetime(2007, 9, 15).date()
    fin = datetime(2008, 7, 1).date()
    print(len(partidos_por_fecha(partidos, inicio, fin)))
    print(len(partidos_por_fecha(partidos, inicio, None)))
    print(len(partidos_por_fecha(partidos, None, fin)))
    print(len(partidos_por_fecha(partidos, None, None)))

test_partidos_por_fechas(partidos)
```

El error que me sale tras ejecutar la función es: 
`TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'NoneType'` Y me señala que se encuentra en el `if` que está dentro de los bucles `for`. No entiendo como tras filtrar los argumentos `inicio` y `fin` cuando tienen `None` antes de los bucles `for`, me siguen entrando variables `None` para comparar con `datetimes`

Me gustaría obtener alguna solución para que funcione la función. Lo siento si hay errores de identación en el código al haberlo pasado aquí y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay algunos errores en el código,:

- La comparación con `None` se recomienda que sea mediante el operador `is`, es decir `if inicio is None`, etc. en lugar de `if inicio == None`. La razón de esto es bastante técnica (si tienes interés puedo explicarlo en una nota final).

  En este caso particular este detalle no afecta al funcionamiento del código, pero acostúmbrate a hacerlo con el `is` como norma general.
- En el `else:` tienes un `==` donde creo que querías hacer una asignación (`=`). Esto tampoco llega a tener importancia porque nunca entra por el `else`, como veremos enseguida, pero obviamente estaba mal.
- El fallo mas importante es la lógica de los `if` con los que quieres asignar valores a `inicio` y `fin` en caso de que no tuvieran uno. Fíjate que si ambos son `None`, el primer `if inicio == None:` se cumplirá, y se ejecutará su cuerpo *sin ejecutar por tanto ninguno de los otros casos*, por lo que en ese caso `fin` se quedará con su valor `None` inicial, y este caso es el que te "rompe".

La solución más simple sería la siguiente:

```
if inicio is None:
    inicio = partidos[0][0][0]
if fin is None:
    fin = partidos[-1][-1][0]
```

Es decir, uso un segundo `if` en lugar de un `elif`. Si `inicio` es `None`, se la asigna un valor por defecto. Después, de forma independiente, se hace lo mismo con `fin`. Si ambos eran `None`, ambos quedarán asignados. La extraña asignación `inicio=inicio; fin=fin` que tenías en el `else:` obviamente no es necesaria, pues deja las variables como estaban.

#### Otra posibilidad

En algunos códigos python puedes encontrarte con el siguiente "truco". Personalmente tengo sentimientos contradictorios con respecto al mismo. Por un lado se reduce el número de líneas de código. Por otro lado hace uso de una característica "rara" que puede considerarse poco legible. Aunque si te acostumbras a verla, acaba resultando bastante legible...

Es así:

```
inicio = inicio or partidos[0][0][0]
fin = fin or partidos[-1][-1][0]
```

Casi puede leerse sin esfuerzo como *"asignale a `inicio` lo que había en  `inicio`, o bien este otro valor (si lo que había en `inicio` era `None`)"*.

La razón por la que funciona es porque el resultado de una expresión `or` en Python es el valor del último término evaluado que hace la expresión cierta, o el del último término si ninguno es cierto.

Así, si por ejemplo `inicio` vale 20, `inicio or otra_cosa` es cierto, (puesto que 20 es considerado como `True` cuando forma parte de una expresión booleana, y por tanto la expresión es cierta ya con sólo evaluar el primer término, por lo que el segundo ni se evalúa), y el resultado sería `20`. Sin embargo si `inicio` es `None` (o cero, o la cadena vacía, u otro valor que sea considerado `False` por python) entonces python debe evaluar `otra_cosa` para determinar el resultado del `or`. El resultado final de la expresión será el valor de `otra_cosa`.

Es un *hack* raro, y no sé si recomendar su uso o desaconsejarlo, pero te conviene conocerlo pues lo verás por ahí escrito muchas veces.

Finalmente python también tiene algo equivalente al operador ternario del C, `v = condicion?valor_cierto:valor_falso`, que en python sería `v = valor_cierto if condicion else valor_falso`.

Usando esto en tu caso:

```
inicio = partidos[0][0][0] if inicio is None else inicio
fin = partidos[-1][-1][0] if fin is None else fin
```

Esto en el fondo no es sino otra forma de poner en menos líneas el `if` que puse en la primera parte de la respuesta. Casi prefiero la versión "en más líneas" pues es más clara.

Comment: Gracias, es el primer lenguaje de programación que he empezado a utilizar, así que no conocía la posibilidad de utilizar "is" en los condicionales ni tampoco la existencia de la otra posibilidad que supongo que me vendrá bien en algunos casos.